# Hstore array attribute won't update in code, but works in console

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

This works in the Rails console:

```
pry(main)> calendar.update({"open_times"=>[{"start"=>"1111-11-11T00:30:00.000Z", "end"=>"1111-11-11T04:00:00.000Z", "title"=>" "}]})
   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> true
```

But the same update method doesn't work anywhere else (model, controller, etc.). The error returned is `TypeError: can't cast Array to`. It doesn't even say what I can't cast array to (though I assume hstore).

Here's my migration for the column:

```
def change
  enable_extension 'hstore'
  add_column :calendars, :open_times, :hstore, array: true, default: [], null: false
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL error logs for the statement Rails ran and the full error.

Answer (score 0):

Restarted all my servers (Rails/Postgres), then tried again. Worked.